# How to create a loop to switch between menu of function in C?

Tags: c

I want to create a menu that has 2 pages because I have too many functions. I came up with the idea to put the head of the loop in the first line of page 1 when I command switch to page 1 (0.Back) I will switch to it and start a new loop but I don't know how.

```
int main () {

struct student list[100];
int numberOfStudent = 0;
int choice;
while(1) {          // infinite loop
    printf("Please choose: \n");
    //page 1
    printf("2. Enter student information: \n");
    printf("3. Print student information: \n");
    printf("4. Calculate average of student: \n");
    printf("5. Ranking student by score: \n");
    // printf("1. Next \n");   //only can seen at page 1
    // Then it switch to next page:
    printf("6. search student by name: \n");
    printf("7. Update student information: \n");
    printf("8. Delete student information: \n");
    // printf("0. Back \n");  // only can seen at page 2

    printf("00. Exit. \n"); // 00 always their in botton.
    printf("Your choice: "); scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            get_list_of_student(list, &numberOfStudent);
            break;
        case 2:
            calculate_average(list, numberOfStudent);
            break;
        case 3:
            print_list_of_student(list, numberOfStudent);
            break;
        case 4: 
            ranking_student_score(list, numberOfStudent);
            break;
        case 5:
            search_student_name(list, numberOfStudent);
            break;
        case 6: 
            update_student_infomation(list, numberOfStudent);
            break;
        case 7:
            delete_student_information(list, numberOfStudent);
            break;
        case 00:
            exit(0);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? Loop seems fine, are you doing exit inside the update_* methods?

Comment: what do you mean by pages, break the menu up into different sections? This menu is small enough to view the whole thing at once in a terminal. As a user I'd be annoyed if this menu showed half itself with a "display the rest" option.

Comment: ya, my issue is: assume I write 50 functions, I want to break into different section and navigate it by entering 1(Next) and 0(Back). When the user type in 1 it will scroll to the next page, when they hit 0 it will scroll to the back page (or section). This is not the final version and I want to improve my skills wish u can help, I'll very appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have created a variable called `page`, assign value 1 because page 1 will always show first and a do-while loop for changing the pages.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct student list[100];
    int numberOfStudent = 0;
    int choice ;
    int page = 1;
    while(1) { // infinite loop
        do{
            if(page == 1)
            {
                //options for page 1
                //get choice
                switch(choice)
                {
                    //case for 1st page options
                    case 0: page = 2;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if(page == 2)
            {
                //options for page 2
                //get choice
                switch(choice)
                {
                    //case for 2nd page options
                    case 0: page = 1;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }while(choice == 0)
    }
    return 0;
}
```